# How to run template_redirect() once?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm generating a random query string (`random_str()`) which I'mm then appending to the URL via a template_redirect.

The issue I'm having is that, the redirect function runs if the page is the homepage (`is_page( 'homepage' )`) and then on redirect, the user is meant to land back on the homepage, with the query string now in the URL.

As such, I'm stuck in a redirect loop because the `if statement` is true after the redirect.

Is there a way to run `template_redirect` once? Or a better way to resolve this?

```html
<?php
function redirect() {
  if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) ) {
    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( array( 'ref' => random_str() ), home_url() );
    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect' );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the `ref` query arg is set, like this

```
function redirect() {
  if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) && !isset($_GET['ref'] ) {
    $redirect_url = add_query_arg( array( 'ref' => random_str() ), home_url() );
    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
  }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect' );
```